# AWS Amplify - Field Level GraphQL Auth on Required Fields

Tags: graphql, authorization, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to set up GraphQL via AWS Amplify so that all users can see part of a Member object (e.g. the name), but only members in certain groups can see other parts (e.g. the e-mail address).

I have set up my `schema.graphql` as follows (note this is a truncated version):

```
type Member @model(subscriptions: { level: off }) @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["MANAGER"]}, {allow: private, operations: [read]}]) {
  membershipNumber: Int! @primaryKey
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  email: String! @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["MANAGER"]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["COMMITTEE"], operations: [read]}])
  dietaryRequirements: String @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["MANAGER"]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["COMMITTEE"], operations: [read]}])
}
```

As I understand it, all logged in users should be able to read `membershipNumber`, `firstName` and `lastName`. Users in the COMMITTEE group should also be able to read `email` and `dietaryRequirements`, and users in the MANAGER group should be able to read/write all fields.

When I try to run a query as a logged in user with no groups though, I get an unauthorized error on `dietaryRequirements` (which is good) but I am able to read `email` without an error (which is bad).

The only difference I can see is that `email` is a required field, whereas `dietaryRequirements` isn't. What am I doing wrong? Do required fields override the authorization rules?